# Export app for localization not including strings created with NSLocalizedString in Xcode 6 Xliff

Tags: xcode, localization, internationalization

I'm trying to localize my app, and I have the following code:

```
self.arrayLabels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSLocalizedString(@"This is a test", "this is a test"),  NSLocalizedString(@"I want my strings to get added to localizable strings file", "strings comment") , nil];
```

So, basically, from what I understand, this should be it, I click `Editor > Export for Localization` and the strings should be there on my `XLiff` file. But, they aren't.

I have two languages, english and portuguese, both `localizable.strings` files are empty.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I have the same problem, sometimes the string just don't show up.

Comment: I also have the same problem. What I have noticed is that files that are included in my Test Target do have the NSLocalizedString converted correctly. I am trying to determine why that is.

Comment: This is incorrect usage of NSLocalizedString because the comments are being declared as strings without the @ in front of the "" which will throw an error when trying to process with genstrings

Answer (score 6):

I discovered that I had a few errors and that is why I could not export from the menu.

I suspect that the error messages are not being returned.

It turns out that the menu is calling existing command line tools so by a process of elimination you may be able to fix your export.

Here are the steps I took to fix my issues. Hopefully they will help you.

Run the command line equivalent

```
xcodebuild -exportLocalizations
```

If you have errors xcodebuild may give file names and line numbers so you should be able to fix the issues.

I had one error that did not have any details.

I then switched to using genstrings as that is what xcodebuild appears to be using in a loop.

```
find . -name '*.m' | xargs genstrings -o somePath/en.lproj
```

this gave the same error

To get the file with the problem I ran each file separately in a loop.

```
for f in `find . -name '*.m'`; do 
    echo "processing $f ...";
    genstrings -o somePath/en.lproj $f
done
```

That gave me the name of the file that had an issue.

It turned out that genstrings did not like a special character I was trying to print using a unicode character \U000000B2.

Answer (score 4):

For the exported XLIFF to contain your localized strings, a few conditions have to be met:

1. The keys must be present in your localized strings file. In your case these files are empty. Which will explain the problem.
2. You must use the keys as string literal with the `NSLocalizedString` macro. For example:

This is the correct way:

```
NSLocalizedString("some_key", "")
```

This will not work:

```
let key = "some_key"

NSLocalizedString(key, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, use the Editor-->"Extract for Localization" menu which will generate the .xliff files (one per language selected). The .xliff files are sent to a translation service for translation. Once the .xliff files are updated by the translation service, you need to import it back into the app using Editor-->"Import Localizations". Once this step is done, for each language, you will find a xx.lproj/ folder with the results of the translation.